# Text classification of an imbalanced dataset

Tags: python, classification

[image: class distribution looks like this][image: this is how the dataset looks like]I have a dataset with size ~ 500k entries. There are 2 columns, 'product description' and 'level 1'. I am developing my model such that it learns from a training set of 350k and based on the product description for test data, it gives the values in 'Level 1'. A simple linear classifier gives an accuracy of 85% which is too low, I am aiming for 97% atleast. I think this might be because the dataset is imbalanced, the level 1 values in the training data are imbalanced. How do I resolve this? Can I make the upsampling minority and downsampling majority work here?

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the class distribution to see the extent of class imbalance and the number of classes you are using for this task?

Comment: @shepan6 i dont understand your question...im new to python..could you check the edited question once again if it makes sense to you? thanks!

Comment: To print the class distribution for one column, you can use `df[column].value_counts()`

Comment: So what I mean by class distribution is the number of examples you have for each each class. @qmeeus has provided a way to get these values. You will need to visualise them by adding .plt(kind = “bar”) (link to visualise data from pandas dataframes  https://queirozf.com/entries/pandas-dataframe-plot-examples-with-matplotlib-pyplot#bar-plot-with-group-by)

Comment: @qmeeus,thanks for the help!

Comment: @shepan6, i have edited now!

Comment: my question really is, as you can see i have multiple minority classes. On the internet what I see is, they have binary classes, denoted by 1 and 0.  How to work around this?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for editing your post. One idea would be to reduce the number of classes by clustering the classes into more "general" ones, if that is possible. That way, you might have a shot at having more balanced "general" classes.

Comment: I don't understand this graph. Could you please run the following and show us the resulting graph? `df['Level1'].value_counts().plot.bar()`

Comment: @shepan6 thanks! I'll try doing it

Comment: @qmeeus , i had written the exact same code to get this graph. Would you need more information to make the ques clearer?

Comment: Are you sure? because normally, running this snippet gives you only one column, and consequently only one item in the legend (or no legend at all actually, I just tried).